# How to redirect in a process substitution?

Tags: bash, process-substitution

I tried to redirect standard error to a file having restricted permissions.  This is what I did:

```
exec 2> >(umask 077; exec > stderr.log)
```

The idea was to redirect standard error to a process, change the umask and redirect once more to the log file.

But it does not work. The command stalls and terminates with 141 after pressing <kbd>return</kbd>.

The Bash manual does not define "process list" in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution).

Can anybody explain the failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `cat` inside sub-process to write the data coming in stdin of the process inside `(...)` which is actually stderr of parent process:

```
exec 2> >(umask 077; cat > stderr.log)
```

Process substitution feeds the output of a process (or processes) into the stdin of another process. Just by doing `exec > stderr.log` you're merely redirecting stdout of sub-process to a file however you're not actually writing anything to stdout inside `>(...)`

Comment: I am not looking for an alternative. I want to understand what is wrong with my command.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I've tried to explain it now.